# What's the best way to simulate being behind China's Great Firewall?

Tags: ssl, firewall, https, amazon-cloudfront, china

We're having issues with an iOS app of ours that uses in-app purchase to unlock downloadable content - but it seems only from China. We see many negative reviews from China for this reason.

Our in app purchase process involves hitting a https server hosted on DigitalOcean, which verifies the receipt and sends back Amazon CloudFront URLs to download from.

I have checked our server with greatfire.org and it comes back green. CloudFront or direct S3 links do not seem to be blocked either.

I have set up an account with PureVPN and used one of their Chinese servers (sending all traffic via them), however I'm not sure if these servers are really in China as the download process works AND I can access Gmail/Facebook/NYTimes.

What is the best way I can simulate being in China, behind the Great Firewall?

Comment: Book a flight to Beijing? Please define what the "best" way means for you.

Comment: I'm a PureVPN user myself and I always get the IP from the country I want. Did you talk to their live chat support? It's really helpful and available 24x7. They will help you get loads of Chinese IPs.

Comment: Many people have had this problem, and the ultimate answer always seems to be to set up a server in China to serve Chinese users.